# Silverlight Drawingbrush

Tags: silverlight, brushes

I'm new in Silverlight, and I'm looking for something like a drawing brush on Silverlight without success. I saw Tamir Khason blog on building a drawing brush in Silverlight and i download the code without any success
i'm taking about the next link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight-DrawingBrush.aspx

Can someone find the way to implement the DrawingBrush???

Thanks.
Eyal

Comment: What are the key features you want from the drawing brush? Is it the tiling or the ability to draw XAML as a brush?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support.
You need to write code with the WritableBitmap class available in Silverlight 3.
We were able to create a VisualBrush kind of thing using the WritableBitmap.